# Why isn't an array being printed properly ? It is no longer an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, artificial-intelligence

So I am making a game of tic-tac-toe in which a user plays against an AI. Programmer assumes he is AI.
There are a few arrays:

`myWins` which contains combinations using which the AI can win.
`yourWins` which contains combinations using which human can win.
`freeWins` which contains combinations that are open to both.

Every time a human makes a move, the program calls the `findWinningCombinations()` and passes it a `__wins` array and the square under consideration. This is intended to be used for both AI and human moves.
Then there is `removeOwnedSquares()` which also takes `__wins` and button under consideration.

The point is:
if `myWins` contains a combination which has a length of 1, AI can win on the next move. If `yourWins` contains a combination which has a length of 1, human can win.

Everything is based on array of `String`s. However, the arrays seize to be arrays mid way.

here is the output:

```
Human Picked::: 5 Human's Array is:: 46,37,28,19
I Could Not Take 5. My Array Now Is:: 39 
Human Picked::: 3 Human's Array is:: 7,28,19,12
```

it was supposed to be `["7","28","19","12"]`

### Complete Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title> 1Player </title>
    <style>
        #stage{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .square{
            user-select : none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;

            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: gray;
            position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="stage">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        const ROWS = 3;
        const COLS = 3;
        const GAP = 10;
        const SIZE = 64;
        var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

        var lotOfButtons = [];
        var isUsed = [false,false,false,false,
                     false,false,false,false,false];


        var myPositions = "";
        var yourPositions = "";
        var youPicked = "";
        var iPicked = "";
        var isX = true;
        var isFirstMove = true;


        var myWins = [];
        var yourWins = [];
        var freeWins = ["123","159","147",
                        "258",
                        "369","357",
                        "456",
                        "789"];

        prepareBoard();
        stage.addEventListener("click",clickHandler,false);


        function prepareBoard(){ //Prepare the board on which the users will play.
            for(var row = 0;row<ROWS;row++){ // Prepare the rows.
            for(var col = 0;col < COLS;col++){ //Prepare the columns.
                var square = document.createElement("button"); //Prepare the button which represents a square.
                square.setAttribute("class","square"); //Make it a square 'officially'.
                stage.appendChild(square); //Add the square to the play area..
                lotOfButtons.push(square); //Keep a record of squares.
                square.style.left = col * (SIZE+GAP) + "px"; //Properly set the horizontal spacing.
                square.style.top = row * (SIZE+GAP) + "px"; //Properly set the vertical spacing.
            }
            }
        }

        function clickHandler(event){
            var targetIndex = lotOfButtons.indexOf(event.target);
            if(targetIndex === -1 || !isX || isUsed[targetIndex]){
                return;
            }
            isX = false;
            isUsed[targetIndex] = true;

            event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/X.PNG)";

            yourMove(targetIndex+1);
            myMove();
        }

        function yourMove(buttonIndex){

            yourWins = findWinningCombinations(yourWins,buttonIndex);
            yourWins = removeOwnedSquares(yourWins,buttonIndex);
            console.log("Human Picked::: " + buttonIndex + " Human's Array is:: " + yourWins);
            if(myWins.length != 0){
                myWins = removeCommonCombinations(myWins,buttonIndex);
            }
        }

        function findWinningCombinations(combinationArray,targetIndex){
            for(var i = (freeWins.length-1);i >= 0;i--){
                if(freeWins[i].indexOf(targetIndex) !== -1){
                    combinationArray.push(freeWins[i]);
                    freeWins.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            return combinationArray;
        }

        function removeOwnedSquares(combinationArray,targetIndex){
            for(var i = (combinationArray.length-1); i >= 0;i--){
                if(combinationArray[i].indexOf(targetIndex) != -1){
                    combinationArray[i] = combinationArray[i].replace(targetIndex,"");
                }
            }
            return combinationArray;
        }

        function myMove(){
            if(isUsed[4] === false){ //TAKE 5
                isFirstMove = false;
                isX = true;
                isUsed[4] = true;
                var fifthSquare = lotOfButtons[4];
                fifthSquare.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/O.PNG)";

                myWins = findWinningCombinations(myWins,5);
                myWins = removeOwnedSquares(myWins,5);
                yourWins = removeCommonCombinations(yourWins,5);

                console.log("I Took 5. My Array Now Is:: " + myWins);

            }else if(isUsed[4] === true && isFirstMove){//FIVE NOT AVAILABLE ?? TAKE A RANDOM SQUARE.
                while(true){
                    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*8);
                    if(isUsed[randomNumber] === false){
                        isX = true;
                        isFirstMove = false;
                        isUsed[randomNumber] = true;
                        lotOfButtons[randomNumber].style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/O.PNG)";
                        myWins = findWinningCombinations(myWins,randomNumber+1);
                        myWins = removeOwnedSquares(myWins,randomNumber+1);
                        yourWins = removeCommonCombinations(yourWins,randomNumber+1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                console.log("I Could Not Take 5. My Array Now Is:: " + myWins);
            }else{//PLAY USING STRATEGY.
                //TODO add logic here
            }
        }

        function removeCommonCombinations(combinationArray,someIndex){
            if(combinationArray.length === 0){
                return;
            }

            for(var i = (combinationArray.length-1);i >= 0;i--){
                if(combinationArray[i].indexOf(someIndex) != -1){
                    combinationArray.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            return combinationArray;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pe2DB/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I request an explanation.